# How to detect collisions in Unity ECS?

Tags: unity, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I am creating a game using the new Data-Oriented Tech Stack (DOTS).

I am using Entities with the [PhysicsShape](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.6/api/Unity.Physics.Authoring.PhysicsShapeAuthoring.html?q=PhysicsShape) and [PhysicsBody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.6/api/Unity.Physics.Authoring.PhysicsBodyAuthoring.html?q=Physics%20Body) authoring components of the new Physics package. Some of my PhysicsShape have "Collison Response: Collide Raise Collision Events" set. Unfortunately [the documentation of the new Physics system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@latest/index.html) doesn't say anything about how I can detect and handle these collision events, and information on the Internet regarding this is very sparse and disorganized. How can I detect when one PhysicsShape collides with another one sending collision messages and run some code in that case?

Answer (score 2):

> **Update:** This answer was originally written based on Version 0.51 of the physics system. The documentation of version 1.0 of the physics system has [a chapter on processing collision detection events](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@1.0/manual/simulation_results.html) that shows a solution applying some of the new idioms. That article might be more helpful than this answer.

You can do this with a [`JobComponentSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.9/api/Unity.Entities.JobComponentSystem.html) which schedules a job implementing [`ICollisionEventsJob`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.physics@0.6/api/Unity.Physics.ICollisionEventsJob.html)*. You also need to set that job as a dependency for the [`EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.6/api/Unity.Entities.EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem.html?q=EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem) using [`AddJobHandleForProducer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.0/api/Unity.Entities.EntityCommandBufferSystem.html#Unity_Entities_EntityCommandBufferSystem_AddJobHandleForProducer_JobHandle_). Here is an example script:

```
using Unity.Burst;
using Unity.Entities;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Physics;
using Unity.Physics.Systems;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionSystem : JobComponentSystem {

    [BurstCompile]
    private struct CollisionJob : ICollisionEventsJob {
        public void Execute(CollisionEvent collisionEvent) {
            Debug.Log($"Collision between entities { collisionEvent.EntityA.Index } and { collisionEvent.EntityB.Index }");
        }
    }

    private BuildPhysicsWorld buildPhysicsWorldSystem;
    private StepPhysicsWorld stepPhysicsWorldSystem;
    private EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem commandBufferSystem;

    protected override void OnCreate() {
        base.OnCreate();
        buildPhysicsWorldSystem = World.GetExistingSystem<BuildPhysicsWorld>();
        stepPhysicsWorldSystem = World.GetExistingSystem<StepPhysicsWorld>();
        commandBufferSystem = World.GetExistingSystem<EndSimulationEntityCommandBufferSystem>();
    }

    protected override JobHandle OnUpdate(JobHandle inputDeps) {    
        JobHandle jobHandle = new CollisionJob().Schedule(
            stepPhysicsWorldSystem.Simulation, 
            ref buildPhysicsWorldSystem.PhysicsWorld, 
            inputDeps);    
        commandBufferSystem.AddJobHandleForProducer(jobHandle);    
        return jobHandle;    
    }
}
```

Note that the physics system will usually generate multiple collision events on what appears to be just a single collision to the player. There is [some debate about whether that's a bug or a feature](https://forum.unity.com/threads/icollisioneventsjob-raises-events-many-times-at-once.840736/).

<sub>* Yes, I am aware how useless this documentation article is right now. Hopefully it will get more useful in future versions of the documentation.</sub>